# android: Writing to firebase database success from application flavor but failed with the other

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application with 2 flavors full & demo ... i had connected the demo version to a firebase database and works well.
To add the second flavor I did the following:

1. I added the flavor to the project and saved its SHA1.
2. I downloaded the JSON file and but it in the app directory.
3. Rebuilt the android project.
4. OAuth 2.0 client key was automatically generated in the Credentials.

Now the first flavor can read and write to the database but the second dose not.
Is there any additional steps to do?

Comment: Are you using different package names for the 2 flavors?

Comment: Yes ... 2 different names

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the problem.
One flavor failed to sign in at the start so failed to write or read from the database.